# Write to .txt file the results from FOR looping in python

Tags: python, python-3.7

My program is search the upper and lower value from .txt file according to that input value.

```
def find_closer():    
    file = 'C:/.../CariCBABaru.txt'
    data = np.loadtxt(file)
    x, y = data[:,0], data[:,1]
    print(y)

    for k in range(len(spasi_baru)):
        a = y #[0, 20.28000631, 49.43579604, 78.59158576, 107.7473755, 136.9031652, 166.0589549, 
               176.5645474, 195.2147447]
        b = spasi_baru[k]

        # diff_list = []
        diff_dict = OrderedDict()
        if b in a:
            b = input("Number already exists, please enter another number ")
        else:
            for x in a:
                diff = x - b
                if diff < 0:
                    # diff_list.append(diff*(-1))
                    diff_dict[x] = diff*(-1)
                else:
                    # diff_list.append(diff)
                    diff_dict[x] = diff
        #print("diff_dict", diff_dict)
        # print(diff_dict[9])
        sort_dict_keys = sorted(diff_dict.keys())
        #print(sort_dict_keys)
        closer_less = 0
        closer_more = 0
        #cl = []
        #cm = []
        for closer in sort_dict_keys:
            if closer < b:
                closer_less = closer
            else:
                closer_more = closer
                break
            #cl.append(closer_less == len(spasi_baru) - 1)
            #cm.append(closer_more == len(spasi_baru) - 1)
            print(spasi_baru[k],": lower value=", closer_less, "and upper 
            value =", closer_more)
            data = open('C:/.../Batas.txt','w')
            text = "Spasi baru:{spasi_baru}, File: {closer_less}, line:{closer_more}".format(spasi_baru=spasi_baru[k], closer_less=closer_less, closer_more=closer_more)
            data.write(text)
            data.close()
        print(spasi_baru[k],": lower value=", closer_less, "and upper value =", closer_more)

find_closer()
```

The results image is here [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHDEz.png)

Then, i want to write these results to file (txt/csv no problem) into rows and columns sequence. But the problem that i have, the file contain just one row or written the last value output in terminal like below,

> Spasi baru:400, File: 399.3052727, line: 415.037138

any suggestions to help fix my problem please? I stuck in a several hours to tried any different code algorithms. I'm using Python 3.7

Comment: you're opening the file in write mode every loop and just rewriting it with the current values of that loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to use w+ or a+ mode when you're trying to append into the same test file.

Instead of doing this:

```
data = open('C:/.../Batas.txt','w')
```

Do this:

```
data = open('C:/.../Batas.txt','w+') 
or
data = open('C:/.../Batas.txt','a+')
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you are overwriting the same file over and over inside the loop, so it will keep just the last interaction. Look for ways to save files without overwriting them.

‘r’ – Read mode which is used when the file is only being read

‘w’ – Write mode which is used to edit and write new information to the file (any existing files with the same name will be erased when this mode is activated)

‘a’ – Appending mode, which is used to add new data to the end of the file; that is new information is automatically amended to the end

‘r+’ – Special read and write mode, which is used to handle both actions when working with a file